# Use AJAX to send SVG string to server as svg file with specified file name

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, svg

I have a string of svg, and want to use AJAX to send it to server as a file: mySVG.svg.

What I am trying to do now is to save the svg string and file name as two properties in an object, and then send the object to the server as json. But I found that the server could not receive the content I sent, and could not create the corresponding .svg file.

May I ask how to achieve it? Here are my codes.

HTML and JavaScript:

```js
let svgData = '<svg width="300px" height="200px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><symbol id="carrot" viewBox="0 0 50 50"><path d="M30 13c-1-3-5-4-7-2h-1l1-11h-3l-1 9-4-7-3 1 5 8-8-4-1 2 9 5h-1c-2 2-3 5-2 7l2 2 5-3 1 2-5 3 8 9 5-3 2 2-5 3 12 14 3-2-8-25-5 3-1-2 5-3-3-8z" /></symbol><pattern id="myPat" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="88" height="88" ><use xlink:href="#carrot" width="30" height="30" fill="orange" transform="rotate(80 45 25) translate(20 0)"></use><use xlink:href="#carrot" width="60" height="60" fill="blue" transform="rotate(50 65 25) translate(40 0)"></use></pattern><rect x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="200px" fill="url(#myPat)"> </rect></svg>'

let filename = "mySVG"

//show svg on the screen
let container = document.getElementById("container");
document.body.appendChild(container)
container.innerHTML = svgData;

//when click the button, send the svg to server
document.getElementById('sendSVG').onclick = function (){
        sendSVG(svgData, filename)
}

//send svg to server
function sendSVG(svgData, filename){
  let obj = {}
  obj.svgData = svgData
  obj.filename = filename
  
  $.ajax({
      url: 'svg_ajax.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(obj),
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: "json",
      success: function () {
          console.log('success')
      }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="sendSVG">Send SVG to Server</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

PHP:

```
//svg_ajax.php
<?php
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    $svgData = $data['svgData'];
    $filename = $data['filename'];
    file_put_contents($filename, $svgData);
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you echo out $data, like `var_dump($data);` and the look at the response coming from your request (browser dev tool). Does it print out both svgData and filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code below:

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
    $svgData = $data['svgData'];
    $filename = $data['filename'];
    file_put_contents('test.svg', $svgData);
```

OR:

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    $svgData = $data->svgData;
    $filename = $data->filename;
    file_put_contents('test.svg', $svgData);
```

**When true**, JSON objects will be returned as associative arrays; **when false**, JSON objects will be returned as objects.

Comment: But you should also replace the static filename `file_put_contents($filename.'.svg', $svgData);'`